Do differential forms fully describe the geometry?
It's clear to me that differential forms contain a lot of geometric information about a differential manifold, they describe volume elements, determinants, orientation, connections, curvature, de Rham cohomology, obstructions, harmonic forms, characteristic classes amd so much more.
But you can think of them as fully antisymmetric tensor fields.

Is there some reason as to why other types of tensors fields are not used?

Do in some sense differential forms fully describe the geometry? Or maybe symmetric tensor fields are somewhat trivial, and don't contain as much information?
It just seems a bit weird that there is so much literature on differential forms, and not so much on other types of tensor fields...

(Semi-)Riemannian geometry has a symmetric tensor field as its primary focus, and that is a vast field, with history even before differential forms were fully laid out.
